# ngModel ngValue change parameter values function

Tags: angular

I am using these values for a function:

**component.ts**

```
ubicacion = 'Cusco';
categoria = 'Arte y Antiguedades';


getAvisos() {
  this.avisos = this.fs.filterByAll(this.ubicacion, this.categoria);
}
```

But since I want these values (`ubicacion` and `categoria`) to change I'm trying this:

**component.html**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="ubicacion" [ngValue]="Cusco"/>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="categoria" [ngValue]="Arte y Antiguedades"/>
```

**component.ts**

```
ubicacion;
categoria;


getAvisos() {
  this.avisos = this.fs.filterByAll(this.ubicacion, this.categoria);
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'input'
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: Remove the `[ngValue]="Cusco"` part. Two-way binding with `[(ngModel)]` will change the value.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use **`ngValue`** and **`ngModel`** together, use ngModel with ngModelChange.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="ubicacion"/>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="categoria" />
```

Comment: But then how can I set an initial value?

Comment: just set the value to this.ubication and this.categoria

Comment: I understand, then I would go back as I had at the beginning. I think I have not raised the question well, the point is that I need those values to change for example through a `select` I think everything changes there?

Comment: For example, can I do this? `<select [(ngModel)]="ubicacion">
      <option value="">Lima</option>
      <option value="">Cusco</option>
      <option value="">Ica</option>
    </select>`  and 

`<select [(ngModel)]="categoria">
      <option value="">Libros</option>
      <option value="">Artes y Antiguedades</option>
      <option value="">Celulares</option>
    </select>`